# Unable to use yum repos whether with baseurl or mirrorlist in CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

Since a couple of days, I'm unable to retrieve repositories data with Yum, in my CentOS 6.5 server.
I did `yum clean all` a dozen of times, it emptied all but didn't solved the problem.

I tried to retrieve things by restricting to the single base repo :

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

`yum --verbose update` results in :

```
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Config time: 0.010
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

And when I configure a `baseurl` instead of a `mirrorlist`, I get this :

```
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Config time: 0.010
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
Determining fastest mirrors
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
```

The server pings `mirror.centos.org` and I can reach without any problem the mirrorlist and the repomd.xml in a web browser. Disabling the plugins changed nothing.
The `mirrorlist` gives a 403 error and a `baseurl` 404...

`rpm -q --verify -f /etc/yum.repos.d/*` results in :

```
S.5....T.  c /etc/issue
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
S.5....T.  c /etc/issue
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
S.5....T.  c /etc/issue
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
S.5....T.  c /etc/issue
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
le fichier /etc/yum.repos.d/isv:ownCloud:community.repo n'appartient à aucun paquetage
.......T.  c /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage.repo
le fichier /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage.repo.rpmsave n'appartient à aucun paquetage
```

« n'appartient à aucun paquetage » means « doesn't belong to any package », in french...

Those problems occur with whatever repo I enable/disable.

Comment: Try this: `yum --verbose update` to see if you can get additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

Need to look at the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and also the output of the following command to be able to debug:

```
$ rpm -q --verify -f /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

I had once got into a similar problem and the quick solution was to disable the offending repo by changing the `enabled` variable to `0` in the correct `yum` config file. But your error is not related to any particular repo.